# X11 forwarding over ssh - can't open display despite X11forwarding is on

Tags: openssh

I am using windows 10 as a client and the Raspberry pi 4( debian buster) as a server.

```
  steven@DESKTOP-8EMNIS1 ~
    $ ssh pi4 -Y -v
    OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
    debug1: Connecting to pi4 [fe80::b5d0:4a20:7aac:baea%3] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspb
    ian-10+deb10u2+rpt1
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2+rpt1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x0400
    0000
    debug1: Authenticating to pi4:22 as 'steven'
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit
    > compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit
    > compression: none
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ubyhDQ0qt2j1WcMpHZlhbnGdzenQ
    e6vf5ON+bm08LRI
    debug1: Host 'pi4' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/known_hosts:6
    debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rs
    a-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug1: Next authentication method: password
    debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
    debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
    Authenticated to pi4 ([fe80::b5d0:4a20:7aac:baea%3]:22).
    debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
    debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
    debug1: Entering interactive session.
    debug1: pledge: exec
    debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from
    console
    debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the an
    si parsing
    debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
    debug1: No xauth program.
    Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
    debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
```

Here is my X11 settings

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no



  xclock
        debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
        debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 40864
        connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory
        debug1: failure x11
        Error: Can't open display: pi4:10.0

but the socket clearly exists and has permission
ls /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug  9 11:26 /tmp/.X11-unix/X0




steven@pi4:~ $ xhost +
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 40866
connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory
debug1: failure x11
xhost:  unable to open display "pi4:10.0"
```

I have x server installed on the pi and it's definately working since I can vnc to the pi and I get a gui. I can also confirm the Cygwin xserver is working locally on windows 10 pc. When export the display variable as `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and load xclock, I can see the xclock gui.

Comment: Do you have an X server installed on your local system? Is it actually running when you try using SSH? That "/tmp/.X11-unix/X0" socket that you refer to looks like it's on the remote system (the pi), correct?

Comment: updated my answer. and yes the socket I mension is on the pi

Comment: Okay, but do you have an X server installed and running on the windows system that you're using to connect to the pi?

Comment: yes locally on windows I can load the xclock application. But only if I load up cygwin terminal and export like this export DISPLAY=:0.0